# How do I speedup adding two big vectors of tuples?

Tags: machine-learning, python, gensim

Recently, I am implementing an algorithm from a paper that I will be using in my master's work, but I've come across some problems regarding the time it is taking to perform some operations.

Before I get into details, I just want to add that my data set comprehends roughly 4kk entries of data points.

I have two lists of tuples that I've get from a framework ([annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy)) that calculates cosine similarity between a vector and every other vector in the dataset. The final format is like this:

```
[(name1, cosine), (name2, cosine), ...]
```

Because of the algorithm, I have two of that lists with the same names (first value of the tuple) in it, but two different cosine similarities. What I have to do is to sum the cosines from both lists, and then order the array and get the top-N highest cosine values.

My issue is: is taking too long. My actual code for this implementation is as following:

```
def topN(self, user, session):
    upref = self.m2vTN.get_user_preference(user)
    spref = self.sm2vTN.get_user_preference(session)

    # list of tuples 1
    most_su = self.indexer.most_similar(upref, len(self.m2v.wv.vocab))
    # list of tuples 2
    most_ss = self.indexer.most_similar(spref, len(self.m2v.wv.vocab))

    # concat both lists and add into a dict
    d       = defaultdict(int)      
    for l, v in (most_ss + most_su): 
        d[l] += v  


     # convert the dict into a list, and then sort it
    _list    = list(d.items())
    _list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    return [x[0] for x in _list[:self.N]]
```

How do I make this code faster? I've tried using threads but I'm not sure if it will make it faster. Getting the lists is not the problem here, but the concatenation and sorting is.

Thanks! English is not my native language, so sorry for any misspelling.

Comment: This question is better suited for stack-overflow.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "too long"? How large are the two lists? Is there a chance your model, and interim results, are larger than RAM and thus forcing virtual-memory paging (which would create frustrating slowness)?

If you are in fact getting the cosine-similarity with **all** vectors in the model, the annoy-indexer isn't helping any. (Its purpose is to get a small subset of nearest-neighbors much faster, at the expense of perfect accuracy. But if you're calculating the similarity to every candidate, there's no speedup or advantage to using ANNOY.

Further, if you're going to combine all of the distances from two such calculation, there's no need for the sorting that `most_similar()` usually does - it just makes combining the values more complex later. For the `gensim` vector-models, you can supply a False-ish `topn` value to just get the unsorted distances to all model vectors, in order. Then you'd have two large arrays of the distances, in the model's same native order, which are easy to add together elementwise. For example:

```
udists = self.m2v.most_similar(positive=[upref], topn=False)
sdists = self.m2v.most_similar(positive=[spref], topn=False)
combined_dists = udists + sdists
```

The `combined_dists` aren't labeled, but will be in the same order as `self.m2v.index2entity`. You could then sort them, in a manner similar to what the `most_similar()` method itself does, to find the ranked closest. See for example the `gensim` source code for that part of `most_similar()`:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/9819ce828b9ed7952f5d96cbb12fd06bbf5de3a3/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L557

Finally, you might not need to be doing this calculation yourself at all. You can provide more-than-one vector to `most_similar()` as the `positive` target, and then it will return the vectors closest to the average of both vectors. For example:

```
sims = self.m2v.most_similar(positive=[upref, spref], topn=len(self.m2v))
```

This won't be the same value/ranking as your other sum, but may behave very similarly. (If you wanted less-than-all of the similarities, then it might make sense to use the ANNOY `indexer` this way, as well.)